# Change linux kernel installation directory

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, installation, kernel

Is it possible to change default destination( /boot/ ) of `make install` at installing custom linux kernel.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Short answer

You need to use `INSTALL_PATH` **environment variable** to change installation directory.

Example:

```
$ export INSTALL_PATH=/tmp
$ make install
```

### Details

From `make help`:

> `install`      - Install kernel using
>
> - (your) `~/bin/installkernel` or
> - (distribution) `/sbin/installkernel` or
> - install to `$(INSTALL_PATH)` and run lilo

From `Documentation/kbuild/kbuild.txt`:

> `INSTALL_PATH` specifies where to place the updated kernel and system map
>   images. Default is `/boot`, but you can set it to other values.

Also, from `Documentation/kbuild/makefiles.txt`:

> `INSTALL_PATH`
>
> This variable defines a place for the arch `Makefiles` to install
>   the resident kernel image and `System.map` file.
>   Use this for architecture-specific install targets.